# Measure how much time an NFC tag stays on RC522

Tags: arduino, nfc, esp32, rfid, mfrc522

I'm trying to measure of much time does a specific NFC tag stays on the RC522 reader through an ESP32. I'm using [MFRC522.h](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) library to use the RFID module, but I don't know what some functions do as it's not very well documented...
I've tried different approaches, but I always end up with the same result. The wires are connected correctly, as dumping the info show the right info.

***Code:***

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 5    // ESP32 pin GPIO5
#define RST_PIN 27  // ESP32 pin GPIO27

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

unsigned long timeStart = 0;
unsigned long timeEnd = 0;
bool tagPresent = false;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();      // init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init();  // init MFRC522
  Serial.println("Use an RFID tag");
}

void loop() {
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    if (!tagPresent) {  // if tagPresent = false, then the tag has just "arrived"
      tagPresent = true;
      timeStart = millis();
    }

    // Removing the next 2 function calls doesn't solve the problem but 
    // it seems to halve the time read in the duration variable

    rfid.PICC_HaltA();  
    rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();

  } else {
    if (tagPresent) {  //at some point there was a tag, but it's gone now
      Serial.print("\n");
      timeEnd = millis();
      unsigned long duration = timeEnd - timeStart;
      Serial.print("Tag NFC stayed for ");
      Serial.print(duration);
      Serial.println(" ms");
      // noted the last tag's time, reset
      tagPresent = false;
    }
  }
}
```

***Output***:

```
    Tag NFC stayed for 51 ms
    Tag NFC stayed for 51 ms    
    Tag NFC stayed for 51 ms    
    Tag NFC stayed for 51 ms    
    ...
```

If I put the tag on the reader it immediatly pops out a line of the output and nothing else for as much as I leave the tag there. If I repeatedly lift and lower the tag towards the reader I get multiple prints like in the output above.

Instead I need that if I leave the tag for 10 seconds, and then remove it, to print "Tag NFC stayed for 10000 ms".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying more accurately the ISO documentation and the library files I managed to solve this by using a WakeUp Call which brings the PICC to the state READY*, which allows to be seen as a "new" tag again.

I placed `MFRC522::StatusCode status = rfid.PICC_WakeupA(bufferATQA, &bufferSize);`
at the beginning of loop(), and called the function again after passing the IsNewCardPresent() and ReadCardSerial() check, and also a the end of loop().
Not sure why, but if I try to remove even one of the three calls, it doesn't work.

```
void loop() {
  MFRC522::StatusCode status = rfid.PICC_WakeupA(bufferATQA, &bufferSize);
  //Serial.print("Before check, status - ");
  //Serial.println(status, DEC);


  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    status = rfid.PICC_WakeupA(bufferATQA, &bufferSize);
    //Serial.print("Inside IF, status - ");
    //Serial.println(status, DEC);
        
    if (!tagPresent) {  // if tagPresent = false, then the tag has just "arrived"
      tagPresent = true;
      timeStart = millis();
      Serial.println("Tag NFC RILEVATO!");
    }

  } else {
    if (tagPresent) {  //at some point there was a tag, but it's gone now
      Serial.print("\n");
      timeEnd = millis();
      unsigned long duration = timeEnd - timeStart;
      Serial.print("Tag NFC stayed for ");
      Serial.print(duration);
      Serial.println(" ms");
     //  noted the last tag's time, reset
      tagPresent = false;
    }
  }
  status = rfid.PICC_WakeupA(bufferATQA, &bufferSize);
  //Serial.print("End, status - ");
  //Serial.println(status, DEC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems wrong and this might be the cause of the problem.

In your loop you check `PICC_IsNewCardPresent` as the name suggests this issues a ISO 14443-3 command and changes the state of the Tag.

On the first iteration of the loop it will return `true` then when you call this again in the second iteration of the loop this will return `false`. This is because the Tag is still present is not a new Tag and is not in the state of a new Tag.

Thus your loop will only every iterate once before giving you a time.

I don't program with the RC522 but for NFC interactions the following re-write of your code logic might work

```
void loop() {
  if (!tagPresent) {
    // Check if a new Tag is presented
    if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
      tagPresent == true;
      timeStart = millis();
    }
  } else {
    // Check the Tag is still present
    if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      // A ready Tag is longer present as UID read has failed
      Serial.print("\n");
      timeEnd = millis();
      unsigned long duration = timeEnd - timeStart;
      Serial.print("Tag NFC stayed for ");
      Serial.print(duration);
      Serial.println(" ms");
      // noted the last tag's time, reset
      tagPresent = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately even though this produces a different output (a costant feed of "Tag NFC stayed for 31 ms" prints to serial, without the need to reposition the tag on the reader), the problem remains. I have very little knowledge of the ISO documentation, would you be able to give me the source?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wg8.de/wg8n1496_17n3613_Ballot_FCD14443-3.pdf) is the documentation, but I have very little experience with this type of documents I have no idea where or what should I be looking for

Comment: Yes, that is the documentation that is of most use, specifically Figure 7 the state diagram. Reading the code of the RC522 driver it seems that `PICC_IsNewCardPresent` sends a ``REQA" and "WUPA", then `PICC_ReadCardSerial` issues the `SELECT`. I'll try and have a look at the RC522 driver code in more detail to see what it is doing may be again `PICC_ReadCardSerial` cannot be used as an "Is existing Tag still present" ping